# Azure Search partitions - How does partitioning work?

Tags: partitioning, azure-cognitive-search

While adding more partitions in Azure Search Service, I see it doesn't require any partition key. We push data from our application and don't use indexer to pull it. Assuming I have only one index and I am using 3 partitions, I have below questions:

1. While pushing a document into the index, how does the service know which partition to create that particular doc in?
2. While querying documents, does the service fan-out query across all partitions every time and then collate the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The service decides which partition the document should be created in based on the document's id. We don't expose which partition a document is in, and you don't need to know this information to search for a document.
2. Yes. Please see our tutorial on [service scalability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning) for more information on how to plan for search and indexing capacity and [performance optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-performance-optimization)

Answer (score 1):

Azure Search automatically balances documents across the available partitions.
When querying documents, the service calls the relevant partitions and then collect the results.

To learn more about partitions\replicas, see [search capacity planning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-capacity-planning).